# how to select values from lists

Tags: ansible

I have 6 hosts defined, these hosts have multiple IPv4's. I need a subset of IPv4's from these lists of IP's.

**This is what I run**

```yaml
- hosts: gluster_mariadb
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        main_nodes_ips: "{{ groups.zicluster |
                            map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses') |
                            list }}"
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: main_nodes_ips
      run_once: true
```

The response is:

```
    ok: [zi04] => {
        "main_nodes_ips": "[ ['172.18.0.1', '192.168.17.209', '172.17.0.1', '169.254.135.46', '169.254.74.141'], ['172.18.0.1', '192.168.17.208', '169.254.118.121', '169.254.53.186', '172.17.0.1'], ['172.18.0.1', '192.168.17.196', '172.17.0.1', '169.254.211.146', '169.254.1.199'], ['172.18.0.1', '192.168.17.159', '169.254.234.110', '169.254.150.56', '172.17.0.1'], ['172.18.0.1', '192.168.17.160', '172.17.0.1', '169.254.113.116', '169.254.97.143'], ['172.18.0.1', '192.168.17.161', '172.17.0.1', '169.254.240.6', '169.254.74.189']]"
    }
```

I try to do a subselection with this:

```yaml
- debug:
    var:
      main_nodes_ips | select('match', '^192') | list
```

This returns no data, I think because it is a list of lists.
So I try to do the subselection earlier. Like this:

```yaml
- hosts: gluster_mariadb
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        main_nodes_ips: "{{ groups.zicluster |
                            map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses') |
                            select('match', '^192') |
                            list }}"
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: main_nodes_ips
      run_once: true
```

This also returns no data.

```
    ok: [zi04] => {
        "main_nodes_ips": []
    }
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```yaml
    ok: [zi04] => {
        "main_nodes_ips":
            [
                "192.168.17.100",
                "192.168.17.101",
                "192.168.17.102",
                "192.168.17.103",
                "192.168.17.104",
                "192.168.17.105"
            ]
         }
```

Comment: Your `run_once` is working, you set only one fact. Your debug taks does not have a `run_once`, though, so the debug is displaying it multiple times.

Comment: Then, for your other issue, from your debug, it Is quite clear that you do have a list of list in `main_nodes_ips`. Flatten it first: `main_nodes_ips | flatten | select('match', '^192') | list`

Comment: Then to get your question better received, try to give us [mre]. You are mixing here multiple issues, what you want, what you tried so far, but you are never giving the input e.g. the relevant part of `groups.zicluster` to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable *main_nodes_ips* is a list of lists

```yaml
main_nodes_ips:
  - - 172.18.0.1
    - 192.168.17.209
    - 172.17.0.1
    - 169.254.135.46
    - 169.254.74.141
  - - 172.18.0.1
    - 192.168.17.208
    - 169.254.118.121
    - 169.254.53.186
    - 172.17.0.1
  - - 172.18.0.1
    - 192.168.17.196
    - 172.17.0.1
    - 169.254.211.146
    - 169.254.1.199
  - - 172.18.0.1
    - 192.168.17.159
    - 169.254.234.110
    - 169.254.150.56
    - 172.17.0.1
  - - 172.18.0.1
    - 192.168.17.160
    - 172.17.0.1
    - 169.254.113.116
    - 169.254.97.143
  - - 172.18.0.1
    - 192.168.17.161
    - 172.17.0.1
    - 169.254.240.6
    - 169.254.74.189
```

You can't use the filter *select* directly. You have to *map* the filter *select* to each item

```yaml
main_nodes_192: "{{ main_nodes_ips|
                    map('select', 'match', '^192.*$')|
                    flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
main_nodes_192:
  - 192.168.17.209
  - 192.168.17.208
  - 192.168.17.196
  - 192.168.17.159
  - 192.168.17.160
  - 192.168.17.161
```